# Magento2.3: Welcome message is not displaying correctly

Tags: magento2.3, customer, login, header

The welcome message is not displaying once the customer logged in to the website and its only displaying after 20 sec, sometimes it's taking even 5 min to display.

Is that because of performance issue or I have missed anything?

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 2):

I think it might issue at code.

The data for the welcome message section coming from `customer-data`.In order to understand it, you have to check how [**Private content**](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/cache/page-caching/private-content.html) worked on Magento 2.

### Study the links:

- https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/cache/page-caching/private-content.html
- https://webkul.com/blog/sections-magento-2/

The data for private content like cart, customer data is stored at local storage of your browser  and data has come from an Ajax reqest at `www.example.com/customer/section/load/`.

If  5mins take time to get response from this URL it means some customization will make delay on reponse from this Url.

So, you have to debug it and fix it by  checking every`section.xml`